# Refactor tree nodes with vectors v_i and multiplications v_i * B into one matrix multiplication A * B

Tags: algorithm, matrix, tree, refactoring, readability

I have a Tree with a complex data-model in each node. Each leaf of the tree has its own vector of doubles `leaf.v`. There is a universal matrix `B`. In my algorithm in each leaf, I calculate a new vector `leaf.u = leaf.v * B`. I found that this computation is currently the performance bottleneck of my algorithm. The complexity is say, `O(n^2)` for one leaf and `O(n^3)` for all leafs combined.

The attentive reader will notice that I can combine the vectors `leaf.v` of all leafs into one matrix `A` and then use a matrix multiplication library to compute `U = A*B`, which can be computed more efficiently than `O(n^3)` [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm). From the matrix `U` I can then extract the vectors `leaf.u` for all the leafs.

This requires some bookkeeping, as the matrix `A` needs to be created and it needs to be tracked which row of `U` will be the `leaf.u` of which leaf and those need to be copied back. How can I do this bookkeeping while still keeping the code readable?

Comment: Running DFS to get a node ordering seems OK, but TBH I think you'd get more mileage improving usage of the memory hierarchy.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Thanks, the processor is quite busy (it's currently 1 thread), but it's one of the things I have in the back of my mind. I think for now I'll go for DFS before and after the multiplication while passing around a stateful object.